# use RStudio's autocomplete for column factors without explicitly defining them?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rstudio

I have a `data.frame` with a column of variable names in the many hundreds whose exact names are hard to remember.  If I somehow explicitly defined them, as I typed them R-Studio would nicely narrow them down for me (example screenshot below), but defining them would totally clutter up the Environment pane.  Is there any trick to somehow define the variable names, but not need them to show up in Environment pane, or maybe there's another method? I'm wanting to isolate and analyze certain variables only.

```
library(dplyr)
variable <- c("del_cvp_total_n", "del_cvp_tot_s", "del_swp_total_north", 
              "desiredvariable", "d418", "x1a_aba")
value <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
df_csv_surrogate <- data.frame(variable, value) %>% mutate(variable = as.factor(variable)

########################################################################################
variablesofinterest <- c("d418","desiredvariable") #where I hope autocomplete can help
########################################################################################

df <-  df_csv_surrogate %>% filter(variable %in% variablesofinterest) #%>% apply functions
```

For example, like this, except without needing to explicitly define `desiredvariable`:

[image]

thank you.

Comment: You could set the names of `vector` to be the values of `vector` and then use `vector %>%` before the `c(` as long as you remember to go back and remove `vector %>%` before executing the code. That would cause the autocompletion you want, but not within quotation marks which is what you are doing in the example. So I'm not sure if this is all worth it.

Comment: Why not just rename the columns, or remove unwanted columns? RStudio also has smart autocomplete when it realises you're trying to reference column names (after `$`, or inside functions like `mutate`, for example)

Comment: @ ngm Ideally it would work within quotes but I'm fine with adding the quotes after - still a huge time saver of hunting down variable names - there's actually thousands. But I'm not sure I can duplicate your method. Could you please demonstrate with the above data? @Calum You, it's just one column: `df_csv_surrogate$variable`. Autocomplete is the term I was looking for - thanks! The data and its single column  is csv model output from another, so `df_csv_surrogate` represents my starting point.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. Why not `df_csv_surrogate %>% filter(variable %in% variablesofinterest)`? It's hard for me to figure out your workflow

Comment: It seems to me that's what I already have.  My workflow is this: I receive a large csv and then need to filter it by variable name. I usually have a rough idea of the variable names I'm looking for, for a given project, but sometimes I get them wrong, so for those times I need to go hunt for their exact spelling. Instead I'd like to leverage autocomplete in my filtering.

Comment: @doconnor Afaik there's not autocomplete for values. I'd opt for a quick `dput(grep("d41|desired", df_csv_surrogate$variable, val=T, ig=T))` if your are unsure.

Comment: @lukeA, got it and thank you.